# I want to convert julian seconds to date in java

Tags: java, date, date-conversion, julian-date

I am getting data like this from a device 1348398464 and its date time is like
time: 11:07:44

date: 28:09:2022

I don't know how it's decoded

Comment: that is probably a unix timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Julian? As in [The Julian Calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) that most of the world stopped using around 1582 (using the gregorian calendar instead which is a very minor tweak), Russia stopped using in 1918 (explaining why the October Revolution was actually **in November**, but in Russia, still on Julian, it was october for them), and which is only still used for orthodox church procedures (such as picking religious dates), and in parts of Morocco?

That seems.. unlikely.

The `java.time` package *no longer includes support for Julian* out of the box. The library that java.time is based on (JSR-310), does. The extra parts are still available as [ThreeTen-extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/).

Include it and you can do this.

In basis it seems like 1348398464 represents the amount of *seconds* that have passed since *midnight, 1980*, at *UTC*, but using the julian calendar.

Using the gregorian calendar instead:

```
int x = 1348398464;
Instant epoch = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(1980, 1, 1), 
  LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
Instant mark = epoch.plusSeconds(x);
System.out.println(mark);
```

1980 is a weird epoch (the computer using world pretty much always uses 1970 instead).

Gets you `2022-09-23T11:07:44Z` which is close to what you wanted. The difference of 5 days is probably indeed explained by the fact you're on the julian calendar (that, or the epoch is midnight, january 5th, 1980 - which is bizarre).

Run the same code but with the julian chronology from threeten-extra:

```
Instant epoch = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(1980, 1, 1), 
  LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();

ChronoZonedDateTime<JulianDate> mark = JulianChronology.INSTANCE.zonedDateTime(epoch, ZoneOffset.UTC);

int x = 1348398464;
mark = mark.plusSeconds(x);
System.out.println(mark);
```

You may have to play around with the epoch value; possibly it's 1980-1-1 in julian and not in gregorian as the above code does (start with `Instant epoch = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0)` instead, then make a julian out of date, then call `.addYears(10)`, then `.addSeconds(1348398464)`, see if it works out that way).

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) IBM BIOS INT 1Ah, DOS, OS/2, FAT12, FAT16, FAT32, exFAT filesystems, ZIP format and derivatives use January 1 1980 as epoch. The article mentions 21 epochs used in computing.

Comment: As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73895631/i-want-to-convert-julian-seconds-to-date-in-java/73895830#comment130484530_73895830), the claim "the computer using world pretty much always uses 1970 instead" is highly debatable. With 2.2 billion iPhone units produced, plus more iPads & Macs, the reference date of 1 January 2001 in `NSDate` class might be the most common.